# Does store-bought salsa have an expiration date/shelf life after being opened?

Tags: storage-lifetime, salsa

So I like salsa, but don’t eat enough of it to use it all in a few days. In general, does store bought salsa—that is stored in the supermarket on open shelves without temperature control—go bad even if refrigerated after opening?

I’ve personally used store bought salsa a few weeks after opening and it smelled fine and there was no sign of mold. Was this an error on my part because I’ve never gotten sick from that stuff; just want a more informed answer if possible.

Comment: To me not really a duplicate and there is no listing for prepared sauces in that link.  A prepared sauce may have stabilizers.  This link indicate 3-4 weeks for Pace.  https://www.campbellsfoodservice.com/product/pace-picante-sauce-medium/

Comment: @paparazzo I agree with you. That answer is quiet thorough and a good reference, but nowhere that I can see does it cover store bought sauces or salsa.

Comment: In a similar position I freeze about half the jar (in a plastic box) when clearing away the meal at which I open it. Defrost in the fridge overnight and you wouldn't know the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all shelf stable foods, it's fully packed with preservatives... And how long it lasts after being opened, that generally depends on the processing and preservatives in the product.

Being on the safer side, I'd say, even after opening and kept sealed airtight, within 1-2 weeks you should be done with it. But I'm sure, the manufacturer has the right information, written somewhere on the jar...

Comment: Good answer. Accepting as “the” answer since this question is closed. As for the information written on the jar, I have bought this brand (Green Mountain Gringo Salsa) more than a few times and there has never been any instructions on the jar other than to refrigerate after opening. In contrast, store bought pasta sauces clearly “go south” pretty quickly a week or two after opening. Thus my question. Anyway, thanks! I appreciate this.

Comment: I definitely had a jar that lacked this information. It was described as tomato chutney but didn't have the large quantity of vinegar you'd expect, so was more like a relish or salsa. It went mouldy after a few weeks so it suggests you're about right